# Python DBus remove signal match (remove signal receiver)

Tags: python, dbus

Community!

I have a little Problem with the Python-DBus-API. I create a signal-receiver and it does its job. However if I try to remove the signal, it won't be removed and the signalhandler (*sigHandler*) is happily called every time the signal matches.

```
class A(threading.Thread)
    bus = None
    mainloop = None
    systemBusMainLoop = None
    signalReceiver = None

    def __init__(self,dbusMainLoop):
        log("Hello.")
        super(A, self).__init__()
        gobject.threads_init()
        self.mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
        self.systemBusMainLoop = dbusMainLoop
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbusMainLoop)
        self.signalReceiver = self.bus.add_signal_receiver(self.sigHandler,
            bus_name="org.bluez",
            dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
            signal_name="PropertiesChanged",
            path_keyword="path")


    def run(self):
        self.mainloop.run()
        log("Running.")

    def end(self):
        log("Shutting down...")
        self.bus.remove_signal_receiver(self.sigHandler,
            self.signalReceiver,
            dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
        #self.signalReceiver.remove() #tried this also
        if (self.mainloop):
            self.mainloop.quit()
        del self.signalReceiver
        log("Bye.")

    def sigHandler(self, interface, changed, invalidated, path)
        print interface
        print changed
        print invalidated
        print path
```

Called:

```
dbusA = A(dbusMainLoop=dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop())
dbusA.run()
#doing something unrelated
dbusA.end() #remove the Signal 
del dbusA
```

Do i miss something? Why ist my sigHandler not removed (or why is my match not removed).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The line you commented out (`self.signalReceiver.remove()`) works.

[`add_signal_receiver()`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.bus.BusConnection-class.html#add_signal_receiver) returns a [`SignalMatch`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.connection.SignalMatch-class.html) instance on which you can call [`remove()`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.connection.SignalMatch-class.html#remove) method to unregister your callback.

The problem in your code snippet is that `dbusA.run()` is a blocking call because it calls `self.mainloop.run()` which itself is a blocking call.

This said, program execution will never reach `dbusA.end()`, thus signal unregistering and quitting the run loop will not happen. You can however call this method from a different thread, or from any event handler of your dbus connection.